# Query adjusts when dragged down but not in ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I want a column that automatically fills in with the person's name when an ID number is added. There is another tab that provides the information

| Date | ID | Member_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/1/21 | 3 | Michelle (AUTOMATICALLY FILLS IN) |

```
=(query('Team / Partner'!A:B,"Select B where A Matches '"&B2&"'",0))
```

The query above works when I drag the formula down. That is when I drag it into row 3 the reference cell changes to B3 as opposed to staying B2.

However, when I put it in the array formula it doesn't automatically update.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B:B),if(ROW(B:B)=1,"Member_Name",(query('Team / Partner'!A:B,"Select B where A Matches '"&B2:B&"'",0))),))
```

The reference table looks like this:

| ID | Member_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Michelle |

I've also tried to remove the number from the reference cell:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B:B),if(ROW(B:B)=1,"Member_Name",(query('Team / Partner'!A:B,"Select B where A Matches '"&B:B&"'",0))),))
```

I tried vlookup but it doesn't work either. I believe this is because the reference table uses an array formula to autofill in the member id numbers. below is the formula i'm using:

```
 =ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B:B),if(ROW(B:B)=1,"Member_ID",FIXED(ROW(A:A)-1,0)),))
```

I also tried an index + match version. But "B2" doesn't automatically change to B3 like id like it to.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B="","",(INDEX('Team / Partner'!B:B,(B2+1)))))
```

**I want B2 to be a relative reference, not an absolute reference. Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1):

I ended up working with the vlookup function. I needed to trim the reference cell.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B:B),if(ROW(B:B)=1,"Member_Name",VLOOKUP(Trim(B:B),'Team / Partner'!A:B,2,False)),))
```

VLOOKUP(**Trim(B:B)**,'Team / Partner'!A:B,2,False)